# Android bug in Slide Activity transition

Tags: android, animation, transition, slide

So in trying to use the `Slide` Activity transition but with a different gravity, the app crashes on using `Gravity.START`, using this:

```
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.START));
```

and I get this error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Invalid slide direction

But yet if you look in the source code, that specific constructor above calls `setSlideEdge()` in which case that method goes through a switch statement to set the Gravity you specified earlier:

```
switch (slideEdge) {
        case Gravity.LEFT:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateLeft;
            break;
        case Gravity.TOP:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateTop;
            break;
        case Gravity.RIGHT:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateRight;
            break;
        case Gravity.BOTTOM:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateBottom;
            break;
        case Gravity.START:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateStart;
            break;
        case Gravity.END:
            mSlideCalculator = sCalculateEnd;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid slide direction");
    }
```

`Gravity.LEFT` works just fine, but because I want RTL support, it only makes sense to instead use `Gravity.START`. I'm confused as to why the default case is executed in this switch statement, and the only explanation for it is it's a bug.

I'd report it to Google but they don't have public ways of reporting API bugs like this, and in this case the bug isn't exactly obvious to fix. So, PSA to anyone that wants to use the Slide animation with a Gravity of `START`.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Transitions work fine on Nexus 5 5.1, but cause a crash on OnePlus One 5.0.2.

Comment: Slide animation is not compatible in api 21 it is work greater than 21.

Comment: @Destro, not that's not correction according to the `Slide` the method `Slide. setSlideEdge()` class was addded in API 21.

Comment: Same issue, for me its crashing on Samsung Note 3.

Comment: I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/issues/116)

Comment: I also encountered this error on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5-Inch (Android 5.0.2, API 21). I didn't get this error on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 6.0.1, API 23). `Gravity.LEFT` works, but `Gravity.START` throws `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid slide direction`

Comment: Hi all, although `Slide` was added in API 21, it didn't support `Gravity.START` and `Gravity.END` until API 22, see my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

This is a problem that crashes on API 21 devices.
The reason is that the initial version of `Slide` in API 21 only supports `LEFT`,`TOP`,`RIGHT` and `BOTTOM` gravitys.

[Slide source from API 21](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/transition/Slide.java#L150)

[Slide source from API 22](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/core/java/android/transition/Slide.java#L179)

One way to solve this is by using [GravityCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GravityCompat.html) from the [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).

```
new Slide(GravityCompat.getAbsoluteGravity(GravityCompat.START, getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection()));
```

The `getAbsoluteGravity()` method takes in the preferred gravity (`START` or `END`) and the current layout direction and returns the gravity as `LEFT` or `RIGHT` as appropriate for the current configuration.